# Question about population and layout of CREATE TABLE results

Tags: sql, select, create-table

This is a real simple question, but I do so very little programming and so I'm just not sure what terminology it is I should be trying to research. Essentially I'm trying to do a SQL query to return results via a CREATE TABLE.

I have a database which contains just two fields: vehicle models and years. For example, it lists 2010-2019 Accords, 2015-2019 Civics, and 2017-2019 Pilots (a total of 18 records).

I want a simple table which creates columns for ALL years - in this case 2010 through 2019 - and rows for ALL models (Accords, Civics, Pilots). In this case, it would be a table of 10 columns and 3 rows. It needs to be populated with a "Yes" or "No" depending on if there is a matching record for that cell.

So there would be a "Yes" in all of the cells next to Accord. But there would be a "No" in the Pilot cells for the 2010-2016 columns; a "Yes" in the rest.

Can anyone point me where I can look to educate myself with this task?

Thanks much,
John

Comment: Without knowing all the details, it sounds more like you want to display the results of a query as a pivot table. It might be easier for you to prototype this in a spreadsheet. Whether you need a database at all would depend on the context of how you're using this data, how long it lives, how often it changes, and its place in your system ecology.

Comment: Assuming I'm not slightly confused here are some thoughts that might be worth adding... As far as terminology and a 'process' this would be the 'flow' as I would think about it:  First you would use `CREATE TABLE` to create a table with columns/rows so that you could then populate that table using an `INSERT` query.  Then you would use standard `SQL` to pull that data back out in a meaningful way.  Perhaps this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the information so far. A pivot table does look like the direction I want to go in as I was able to basically produce the output I am looking for in Excel. In this case, the pivot table has columns for the years 2010-2019 and rows for the three vehicle models. In each cell, there is either nothing, or a '1'. This is due to Excel using a Value of "Count of Available" for the matching records, which is not preferred. As the rows are unique, I would rather it use a "Yes" instead of a '1'. Appreciate the feedback and will update for other noobs as I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to bring in the results you want.  So:

```
select m.model, y.year,
       (case when t.model is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end) as flag
from (select distinct model from t) m cross join
     (select distinct year from t) y left join
     t
     on t.model = m.model and t.year = y.year;
```

Note:  This assumes that all models and all years that you care about are in the table.